# Wrong when I convert ulong -> double -> ulong with large number

Tags: c#

If small number then it worked, but with larger number then it was wrong. My example code below.

```
    public void TestZZZZZZZZZ() 
    {
        ulong val = ulong.MaxValue;  // val = 18446744073709551615
        string s = string.Format("{0}", val);

        double d = Convert.ToDouble(s);
        ulong result = ((ulong)d;  // result = 0 <-- WRONG

        Assert.AreEqual(val, result);
    }
```

Some test data result:

- If val = 1229 then it OK
- If val = 90071992549900000 then it OK.
- If val = 90071992549900001 then result = 90071992549900000
- If val = 90071992549900009 then result = 90071992549900016

Is there any my wrong? please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry not having C# on hand. This sounds like precision problem. Can you try to use "decimal" instead of "double" in your test code and tell us if it can be resolved? According to MSDN double (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) only having 15-16 digits of precision whereas decimal (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) reaches 28-29 significant digits.

Answer (score 7):

That's because `long` holds 64 bits of data, and significant precision of `double` is only 53 bits.

Answer (score 2):

double Have precision of 16 digits. So test your number for 16 digits.

```
ulong val = 1234567890123456; // 16 digits
double d = val;
ulong result = (ulong)d;

Console.WriteLine(val == result); // prints true
```

After this you will loose precision.

```
ulong val = 12345678901234567; // 17 digits
double d = val;
ulong result = (ulong)d;

Console.WriteLine(val == result); // prints false
```

Answer (score 2):

From [Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx):

Long:Signed 64-bit integer

Double:64-bit floating (15-16 digits Precision)

So result is not same.
So if you have just 16 digits your assert is ok.
Like M.kazem Akhgary answer.

Answer (score 0):

My solution here was use **decimal** to contain value for converting (instead double).

Thanks for all your supporting! 
Trong.